# CSS align text and input field

Tags: html, css, forms

Assuming the dashes represent an HTML input text field and the Latin text is plain text, how do I change the following format

```
Lorep ipsum -----------
   Dolor sit amet ------------
  Consectetuer adipiscing elit -----------
```

to this using CSS?

```
                 Lorep ipsum ------------
              Dolor sit amet ------------
Consecteteur adipiscing elit ------------
```

And also to this?

```
Lorep ipsum                  ------------
Dolor sit amet               ------------
Consecteteur adipiscing elit ------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `float` them, or use `text-align` on the text.

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bXAbQ/) ... or ... [**alternative jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bXAbQ/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="form">
    <div>
        <label>Some random text:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>More text:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Even more text:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:right;
}

label {
    float:left;    
}
input {
    float:right;    
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The early bird gets the worm

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes It's not a bad idea to use table,

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Lorep ipsum</td><td>-----------</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Dolor sit amet</td><td>-----------</td></tr>
    <tr><td> Consectetuer adipiscing elit</td><td>-----------</td></tr>
</table>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3YM9q/1)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <span class="one">test</span>
    <input type="text" />
</p>
<p>
    <span class="one">test</span>
    <input type="text" />
</p>
<p>
    <span class="one">test</span>
    <input type="text" />
</p>
<p>
    <span class="two">test</span>
    <input type="text" />
</p>
<p>
    <span class="two">test</span>
    <input type="text" />
</p>
<p>
    <span class="two">test</span>
    <input type="text" />
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.one{
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:right;
}

.two{
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d4LAC/